# python: append to list in object in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand something with lists in python.

```
class Foo:
    vals=[]
    id=-1
    j=-1
    def __init__(self,ID):
        self.id=ID

foos=[]
for i in range(10):
    foos.append(Foo(i))

for j in range(15):
    for f in foos:
        if f.id == j:
           f.vals.append(j)
           f.j=j
           break

for f in foos:
    print(str(f.j)+" "+str(f.vals))
```

The Output is:

```
0 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
1 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
2 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
3 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
4 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
5 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
6 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
7 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
8 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
9 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Why isn't the output like:

```
0 [0] 
1 [1] 
...
```

Or what I have to change to get this output?

Thanks.

Comment: Because you made `vals` a class attribute, shared by all instances of the class, rather than an instance attribute. So, each instance is `append`ing to the same shared list.

Comment: Your question isn't clear.  First, once you've traced the intermediate results and data flow of the posted code, what aspect of the operation do you not understand?  This isn't a site for asking a wholesale walk-through of a block of code.  Second, what have you tried to produce the desired output?  The posted code is over-kill for such simple output.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate question that already has a great answer that we can find for you, but the short version is to get rid of `vals=[]` and instead put `self.vals = []` inside the `__init__` method. And probably the same for `id` and `j`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating 'class variables'. This means that the vars are shared between all instances of the class.

You want your vars to belong to each instance of the class `Foo`, so you should creating 'instance variables' by defining them inside of `__init__`.

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self,ID):
        self.id=ID
        self.vals=[]
        self.j=-1
```

Output:

```
0 [0]
1 [1]
2 [2]
3 [3]
4 [4]
5 [5]
6 [6]
7 [7]
8 [8]
9 [9]
```

You can see a [working example on repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/ImaginativeHardtofindEngineering).

You can see a [good explanation on Digital Ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/understanding-class-and-instance-variables-in-python-3).